# Выбрать интервалы по заданному количеству времени из Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Есть `Dataframe` в котором содержатся `datetime` поминутно от одной даты до другой.
Пример за два дня:

```
0    2012-01-01 00:00:00
1    2012-01-01 00:01:00
2    2012-01-01 00:02:00
3    2012-01-01 00:03:00
4    2012-01-01 00:04:00
...                  ...
2875 2012-01-02 23:55:00
2876 2012-01-02 23:56:00
2877 2012-01-02 23:57:00
2878 2012-01-02 23:58:00
2879 2012-01-02 23:59:00

[2880 rows x 1 columns]
```

Нужно создать функцию, которая получала бы Dataframe и количество времени, а возвращала рандомно выбранные интервалы времени по 30 минут (из этого `Dataframe`), сумма времени которых была бы равна введенному количеству времени.

Например: вводим время 3 часа, тогда нам нужно получить 6 случайных интервалов по 30 минут, которые бы не накладывались один на другой.

Код с начальными данными:

```
start = datetime.datetime.strptime('2012.01.01 00:00', '%Y.%m.%d %H:%M')
end = datetime.datetime.strptime('2012.01.02 23:59', '%Y.%m.%d %H:%M')

df = pd.DataFrame({"time":pd.date_range(start, end, freq="T")})
```

Comment: Ну сделайте для всего периода интервалы по 30 минут, а потом выбирайте нужное их кол-во через `random.choise`

Comment: @CrazyElf если сделать интервалы по 30 минут, то рандомизация будет ограничена этими интервалами (например 00:30-01:00, 14:00-14:30 и тд и тп, а интервалы должны быть рандомными (например 12:27-12:57, 18:53:18:23 и тд)

Comment: ошибся в примере последнего интервала, там 18:53-19:23

Comment: Что-то я ничего не понял. Если у вас 3 часа и 6 интервалов, то вам надо нарезать прямо подряд по 30 минут, у вас лишнего то времени нет, чтобы со сдвигом интервалы делать. А, или общее время у вас вот это сутки которое, а надо из них нарезать 3 часа?

Comment: Ничего не понять в этом вопросе. Что есть сумма времени? Что значит случайные данные, но с интервалом? Интервал подразумевает отрезки равной длины. Можете привести воспроизводимые примеры входных и выходных данных? Например на входе интервал 5 мин., а на выходе 10 мин.

Comment: @CrazyElf да, верно, общее время это сутки, а из них нужно выбрать 6 интервалов по 30 минут со случайным начальным временем (в моем примере)

Comment: @MaxU у нас есть Dataframe,  пример которого я навел в вопросе, с ним все понятно? нужно написать функцию, которая на вход получает количество времени в часах, а на выход возвращает интервалы времени по 30 минут со случайным начальным временем. Суммарное время интервалов должно соответствовать введённому количеству времени. Если мы вводим 0.5 часа (30 минут), то на выходе будем иметь всего один интервал в 30 минут (например 14:22-14:52). Если на вход пойдут 3 часа, то на выход 6 интервалов по 30 минут (например 06:30-07:00, 07:51-08:21,  12:20-12:50, 16:16-16:46, 20:13-20:43, 21:05-21:35)

Comment: @TedMosby, т.е. на входе фрейм с __единственным__ столбцом (`timestamp`) с интервалом 1 мин. и на выходе другой фрейм тоже с __единственным__ столбцом, но с интервалом 30 мин., который начинается в случайное время и должен содержать N строк - я правильно понял вопрос?

Comment: @MaxU на выходе фрэйм из нескольких интервалов по 30 минут, количество этих интервалов зависит от времени которое так же подается на вход. посмотрите ниже ответ strawdog. Там все работает как нужно, я сейчас пытаюсь вмонтировать его решение в остальной код моей программы. Если все будет работать как надо, то закрою вопрос.

Comment: просто если у вас действительно только один столбец, то незачем городить огород - воспользуйтесь готовой функцией  `pd.date_range()`, а если у вас больше столбцов, то в вопросе отсутствует __воспроизводимый__ пример данных...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос,

Исходные:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime.strptime('2012.01.01 00:00', '%Y.%m.%d %H:%M')
end = datetime.datetime.strptime('2012.01.02 23:59', '%Y.%m.%d %H:%M')

df = pd.DataFrame({"time":pd.date_range(start, end, freq="T")})
```

Далее:

```
# примерная функция вывода нарезок

df_copy = df.copy()
def get_samples(df_copy):
    t = 3 # количество минут в каждой нарезке. здесь для примера = 3*2 = 6 минут
    num = 6 # количество нарезок датафрейма
    x = 0
    while x < num:
        rnd = df_copy.sample(n=1, random_state=1).index.values[0]
        smpl = df_copy.iloc[rnd-t:rnd+t]
        df_copy=pd.concat([df_copy, smpl]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
        print(smpl)
        x+=1

get_samples(df_copy)
```

Разумеется, здесь нет проверок на границы дадафрейма, но принцип будет понятен
результат:

```
                    time
2159 2012-01-02 11:59:00
2160 2012-01-02 12:00:00
2161 2012-01-02 12:01:00
2162 2012-01-02 12:02:00
2163 2012-01-02 12:03:00
2164 2012-01-02 12:04:00
                   time
391 2012-01-01 06:31:00
392 2012-01-01 06:32:00
393 2012-01-01 06:33:00
394 2012-01-01 06:34:00
395 2012-01-01 06:35:00
396 2012-01-01 06:36:00
                    time
2203 2012-01-02 12:43:00
2204 2012-01-02 12:44:00
2205 2012-01-02 12:45:00
2206 2012-01-02 12:46:00
2207 2012-01-02 12:47:00
2208 2012-01-02 12:48:00
                    time
1149 2012-01-01 19:09:00
1150 2012-01-01 19:10:00
1151 2012-01-01 19:11:00
1152 2012-01-01 19:12:00
1153 2012-01-01 19:13:00
1154 2012-01-01 19:14:00
                    time
2105 2012-01-02 11:05:00
2106 2012-01-02 11:06:00
2107 2012-01-02 11:07:00
2108 2012-01-02 11:08:00
2109 2012-01-02 11:09:00
2110 2012-01-02 11:10:00
                    time
2870 2012-01-02 23:50:00
2871 2012-01-02 23:51:00
2872 2012-01-02 23:52:00
2873 2012-01-02 23:53:00
2874 2012-01-02 23:54:00
2875 2012-01-02 23:55:00
​
```